# Atx psu turns off

Tags: power-supply, power, current

I have an ATX power supply from an old computer probably 10 years old. The psu has the usual black, red, orange, yellow wires for 0,5,3.3,12v . Besides these it also has pink for 5v, brown and orange wires for 5 and 3.3v. Also blue wire for -12v.

After switching the psu on and joining the green wire and black, it didnt require load for switching on the psu, as the wires already showed the voltages with multimeter.
When I connected a dc motor across red and yellow wire, there was no problem but when I connected it with 3.3v (orange) and the other wires it shuts down except the violet wire for 5v.

Could anyone help me with this problem? What should I do to use the 3.3v for more current? Thanks in advance.

And sorry I connected motor between 0 and 5 and 0 and 12 v not between 5 and 12v. And I meant connecting dc motor between 3.3v and ground and again other wires and ground.

Comment: You should only connect a load between a voltage output and ground, not between 2 voltage outputs. The outputs aren't designed to sink current. (Except for the -12V, obviously)

Comment: Sorry for confusion, I only connected it between ground and only 1 of the wires except 5 &12v ones.

Comment: if that voltage isn't enough for the motor to spin, it could act as a dead short.

Comment: Yes, dead short: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ATX

Comment: No I am pretty sure about it as use just a pencil lead as resistive load also turns it off.

Comment: I just found out that there is 3.3v sense wire which was written in the pcb as 3.3v S. I didnt connect it to anything so maybe the dc motor caused pd drop that couldnt be sensed by the sense wire and the 3.3v rail shut off. Is my guess correct?

Comment: You did not say you disconnected all the wires, so nobody expected that you have disconnected the 3.3V sense wire. It is not known how it is internally connected so leaving it disconnected from the 3.3V supply can cause any problems, including erratic operation, not working at all, or damage to the supply.

Comment: Normally the 3.3V sense wire is connected at the plug for the motherboard, there are two wires going to the same pin.

Comment: Is the sense wire actually disconnected from 3.3 V?

Comment: Yeah I was surprised too when I found that there was a sense wire separately.

Comment: But the problem is on using dmm in diode mode it shows a value of 10 so 10ohm is betn the 3.3v and sense wire. Is it normal to show this? I mean why would there be a sense wire separately with 10ohm internally between it and 3.3v one?

Comment: @user268759 It is not possible to reliably measure components in circuit. It may have 10 ohms to 3.3V or not but unless you have reverse-engineered the schematics it tells you nothing. The sense wire is a feedback to measure what 3.3V output actually has, and it does not measure the output at the power supply end, but what the voltage is at the connector/motherboard end of the wiring. It can't get feedback when it is disconnected

Answer (score 2):

As there is no other load on the power supply, connecting the motor between 12V and 3.3V supplies will feed in current from the 12V output **into** the 3.3V output, and in general the regulated outputs only source out current and cannot sink current.

So most likely what happened is that the extra current into 3.3V supply made the 3.3V supply voltage to rise upwards and the monitoring circuit detected the overvoltage condition and shut down the power supply before further damage happens.

The power supply works as expected. It is not intended usage to connect loads between 12V and 3.3V outputs.

EDIT: With the new info provided, disconnecting the 3.3V sense wire can lead to all kinds of issues as it is not a valid condition to run the power supply with sense disconnected.

Comment: If you attach a resistor between 3.3V and ground which uses more current than the motor (even when stalled), now you may use the power supply to maintain 3.3V (as it will compensate for the amount of current the resistor wants that *isn't* going through the motor), but it seems a bit wasteful. I think.

Comment: Anytime I try to use more current it shuts off as well.

Comment: @user268759 As you may have noticed, ATX power supplies may not perform very well as general purpose laboratory power supplies for random experiments. Using them so that only one output has some load and the rest are completely unloaded is a scenario that does not usually happen to an ATX supply so they may not handle it well.

Comment: Yeah I also realized that. It felt just nice to have one more power rail but well, 5v and 12v ones are working just fine and should be more than enough for most of application. Thanks for the advice. :)

Answer (score 1):

Most likely without a load on the 5V , it will not regulate well as often this is the sole feedback and no load on 5V makes it unstable when pulse loaded on 3.3V.  All outputs by design with a balanced MOBO peripheral minimum load are mutually coupled by the magnetic design.

Comment: ATX PSUs made within the last 20 years shouldn't need a 5v dummy load; basically if it has a 24 pin connector you're good to go.

Comment: But there is just this problem with 3.3v rail.

Comment: Yes I would expect that on 3.3V  . Do what I said. add a dummy load on 5V. If that fails your back EMF is too high and needs some power Schottky clamp diode from switch to supply and or RC snubber.